# Form Element Resizing After Submission

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a system that makes use of a form to enter some data into a database. The system works as expected except for an issue with the display of the form after it has been submitted. When the form is submitted the page reloads and will show the info submitted as placeholder text inside of the form fields, and the "Save Changes" button will display as "Changes Saved!" for a few seconds. However, some of the input fields width property gets altered as well. Specifically my half-width form elements.

The width for these elements is defined as width: `calc(50% - 24px)`, which is `265px`. Additionally, there is a `5px` padding and `2px` border for these elements. This comes out to a total width of `279px`, as expected. However, when the form is submitted and the page is reloaded the total width of the element comes out as `265px`, retaining the `5px` padding and `2px` border, but dropping the internal width to `251px`. Nowhere in my code is there anything that changes the width ever, and checking with dev tools shows that the width, padding, and border I defined are still there. This has the rather annoying effect of shifting both elements over after the form is submitted. Navigating to another page and back resolves the issue.

I have tried using !important and have checked over all of the code (JavaScript) echoed out from `PHP` when the submission is successful that interacts with the form in a capacity for changing things, and nothing should have this impact. I only change the color and text of the submit button.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit 1:**
The code below is a snippet of the entire form, excluding the PHP. I have modified the code so that clicking save changes does not submit the form but will show the change for the submit button, as otherwise submitting makes the form vanish. The error does not occur in the snippet of code however as a result of not "reloading" the page.

```js
function success() {
  var button = document.getElementById('clientInfoBtn');
  var normalColor = button.style.backgroundColor;
  var normalValue = button.value;
  button.style.backgroundColor = '#33cc33';
  button.value = 'Changes Saved!';
  setTimeout(function() {
    button.style.backgroundColor = normalColor;
    button.value = normalValue;
  }, 3000);
  return false;
}
```

```css
.standardFormBox {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 600px;
}

.standardFormBoxInner {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.standardFormHeading {
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  font-size: 16pt;
  color: white;
  background-color: #1975FF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.standardFormBtn {
  color: white;
  font-size: 14pt;
  background-color: #1975FF;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.standardFormBtn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #0052cc;
}

.standardFormInput {
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.sfiMultiLabel {
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
}

.sfiHalf {
  width: calc(50% - 24px);
}

.sfiText {
  font-size: 14pt;
  margin: 0;
}

.sfiTextHalf {
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
}

.sfiTextFull {
  width: 100%;
}

.sfiFull {
  width: 100%;
}

.sfiLeft {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<form name="accountInfoForm" method="POST">
  <div class="standardFormBox">
    <p class="standardFormHeading">Business Billing Information</p>
    <div class="standardFormBoxInner">
      <p class="sfiText sfiTextHalf">Business Name</p>
      <input type="text" name="cBusiness" placeholder="" class="standardFormInput sfiFull">
      <p class="sfiText sfiTextHalf">Name On Bank Account</p>
      <input type="text" name="cName" placeholder="" class="standardFormInput sfiFull">
      <p class="sfiText sfiTextHalf">Billing Email</p>
      <input type="email" name="cEmail" placeholder="" class="standardFormInput sfiFull">
      <p class="sfiText sfiTextHalf">Street Address</p>
      <input type="text" name="cStreet" placeholder="" class="standardFormInput sfiFull">
      <p class="sfiText sfiTextHalf">City</p>
      <input type="text" name="cCity" placeholder="" class="standardFormInput sfiFull">
      <p class="sfiText sfiLeft sfiTextHalf">State</p>
      <p class="sfiText sfiTextHalf">ZIP</p>
      <input type="text" name="cState" placeholder="" class="standardFormInput sfiLeft sfiHalf">
      <input type="text" name="cZip" placeholder="" class="standardFormInput sfiHalf">
      <p class="sfiText sfiTextHalf">Phone Number</p>
      <input type="text" name="cPhone" placeholder="" class="standardFormInput sfiFull">
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="clientChangeInfo" value="Save Changes" class="standardFormBtn" id="clientInfoBtn" onclick="return success()">
</form>
```

Comment: can you please put your code in Snippet or js ifddle.

Comment: I added the code that is in question for you to view, however since the impact is after the page reloads you can't see the impact defined in the question.

Comment: When i fill the form and save, after saved there is no change nor design issue. I am not replicating your issue.

Comment: Please reference the note I made by EDIT 1, no change occurs because in normal usage the page would reload and then display the new information, however reloading here would cause the form to vanish instead, so I changed the code so you could see the changes that are intended to happen from the JavaScript